# onload function inside a document.ready can be written

Tags: jquery

> If I write like this only document.ready function is called and onload is not executed.Is that correct to call onload function.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  alert("document");
    $(window).on('load',function() 
    {
      alert("Loaded");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you could end up missing the `load` event that way.

If you want to hook the load event, do it when you hook document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...do whatever you need here, HTML is loaded but images and such aren't necessarily loaded yet...
});
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // ...full window load is done...
});
```

**But**, there's almost never any reason to use *either* of these features outside of a library. You only need `ready` if you don't control the `script` tag (if you do, either put it at the end of the body just prior to the closing `</body>` tag, or put [`defer`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer) or [these days] `type="module"` on it). You only need `load` if you **really** need to wait until all stylesheets, images, and other such are loaded before your code runs.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() function is called when the dom is fully loaded and  $(window).on('load',function() {}) is an eventhandler which executes when the window is loaded not the specific page.So both of them serves different purpose according to requirement. So it is not correct to write in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to be sure both events have fired, here's how you do it:

```js
var loaded = false;
var ready = false;
function do_the_stuff() {
  if (ready === false || loaded === false) return;
  if (ready && loaded) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
$(document).ready({
  ready = true;
  do_the_stuff();
});
$(window).on('load', function() { 
  loaded = true;
  do_the_stuff();
})
```

Now "the stuff" will only be done after both events have fired.